# Apply an overlay image over an existing svg and then export to png via inkscape cli

Tags: image-processing, svg, command-line-interface, inkscape

How to apply a watermark image for eg `watermark.png` onto an existing svg `item.svg` and convert that to `item.png`

currently, I am using this inkscape command line to export to png of width 1000. This works fine, but how to add watermark.png over exported png image.

```
inkscape -z item.svg -e item.png -w 1000
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is applying the watermark to the bitmap image exported by inkscape. Under *nix, I would recommend magick++ toolkit, there are many options and the particular choice will depend on the watermark image you want. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/